# VirtualHost in httpd

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I try more way to set sub domain by virtual host, it it is not working. 
I have a domain can connect via internet. With this alias I set document root is `/var/www/html`.
I make a second document root is `/data/www/html` and I want set sub domain and can be access via internet.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /data/www/html
    ServerName example.info
    ServerAlias sub-example.info
    ErrorLog /data/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /data/www/html/request.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

This is one of the my virtualHosts. But when I restart apache. Document root `/var/www/html` missing when I connect by my domain

I has read how to set virtualhost at [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: You say `This is one of the my virtualHosts`, can you show us the other(s)?

Comment: I change the my virtual host` (ServerName and ServerAlias)` to can connect to new `Document Root /data/www/html ` such as: `1. ServerName sub-example.info ServerAlias example.info 2. ServerName sub-example.info ServerAlias example.info/sub `